# Join SQL Table?

Tags: sql

I have these tables.

```
tables
#__qa_question
    qid, 
    user_id,
    date_add,
    date_modify,
    question,
    publish
   
#__qa_answer
    aid,
    operator_id,
    date_add,
    date_modify,
    answer,
    publish
   
#__qa_category
    catid,
    name,
    publish
#__qa_answer_xref 
    id,
    qid,
    aid
#__qa_category_xref
    id,
    catid,
    qid
```

How can   Join these table question,category,answer get the following result

```
s/n  Question  date  publish     user name        category       answer   publish
1       x       xxx  no             xxxxx           xxxx            xx      yes
```

Comment: What do you mean by "truncate"?

Comment: I can't see a common field which links a question to an answer?

Comment: In that case, see @Chris's comment.  You currently can't as no relationship exists.

Comment: Presumably there is an #__qa_answer_xref table that hasn't been given in the question.

Comment: you are right ,just updated.thanks

Comment: Python, did you just edit the question and remove all the contents? Why? Also, was there a reason that my answer didn't work for you? I noticed that you accepted it, then revoked and gave the tick to keshav veerapaneni.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

select
q.question as question,
q.date_add as date,
q.publish as publish,
q.user_id as user,
qcat.name as category,
qans.answer as answer,
qans.publish as anspublish
from 
 #__qa_question as q, 
 #__qa_category_xref as qcatref,
 #__qa_category as qcat,
 #__qa_answer_xref as qansref
 #__qa_answer as qans
where 
q.qid = qcatref.qid
and qcat.catid = qcatref.catid
and q.quid = qansref.qid
and qans.aid = qansref.aid

---

Answer (score 1):

Here's a starter for 10 (I'm assuming that the user_id column contains the user name, but there is probably another table in reality):

```
SELECT q.question AS "Question",
       q.date_add AS "date",
       q.publish AS "publish",
       q.user_id AS "user name",
       c.name AS "category",
       a.answer AS "answer",
       a.publish AS "publish"
  FROM #__qa_question q
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #__qa_category_xref cx ON (cx.qid = q.qid)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #__qa_category c ON (c.catid = cx.catid)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #__qa_answer_xref ax ON (ax.qid = q.qid)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #__qa_answer a ON (a.aid = ax.aid)
```

Using outer joins ensures that you will see every question even if it has no answers or no categories.

Of course if (as suggested by the xref tables) there are many answers and many categories for each question then you will see lots of rows for each question, one for each answer and category combination.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming #__qa_category_xref.id is FK to #__qa_answer. (No  #__qa_answer_xref table assumed).

```
select q.qid as [s/n], question, q.date_modify as [date], q.publish as publish
, user_id /*as no user table specified*/, c.name as category, answer, a.publish
from #__qa_question as q
join #__qa_category_xref as xref on q.qid = xref.qid
join #__qa_answer as a on a.aid = xref.id
join #__qa_category as c on c.catid = xref.catid
```